# Receiving Media Button Intent on an LG G4

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver, android-mediasession

This problem occurs on LG G4 (Android version 5.1) only.

My Application uses headset's play/pause button to trigger an action. I implemented the BroadcastReceiver as:

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() { super(); }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            return;
        }
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event == null) {
            return;
        }
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Log.v("MediaButton: ", "Action_Down");        
            // Some action
        }
   }
}
```

And I am registering the receiver with:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
filter.setPriority(10000);
registerReceiver(new MediaButtonIntentReceiver(), filter);
```

This code works perfectly on various smartphones, except LG G4. Lg phone almost always starts the Music Widget and my logcat says:

```
01-08 11:49:30.230 22031-22031/com.example.test I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK, scanCode=226, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=285960, downTime=285960, source=0x101 } to com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{10cba8ca V.E..... R....... 0,0-1440,2560}
```

After some search on SO, I implemented a MediaSession to make my application the sole receiver of the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent with the below code:

```
MediaSession mediaSession = new MediaSession(this, "MediaSessionTAG");
   mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS);
     //Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON); // this doesn't work either
   Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class);
   PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
   mediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(pIntent);
mediaSession.setActive(true);
```

How can I make my application the only receiver of the Media Button intent and have the MediaButtonIntentReceiver (BroadcastReceiver) called at each button action?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had same problem and I solved it using `KeyEvent.Callback`, see the example:

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends Activity{

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
       Log.e("buttons","yes master, button pressed is= "+KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode));
       return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int count, KeyEvent event) {
       return false;
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes, eventually I solved the problem like you did. Thank you for submitting a solution.